# Great circle and how to "imagine" it in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I am currently working on a riddle. I have to search and locate a person, but I do not know, where he is. I only have some informations, concerning the probability where he might be.

> A satellite offers the following information: with 95% probability the
> person is located within 1200m distance of the satellite’s path
> (assuming a normal probability distribution). And it is further known
> that the Satellite path is a great circle path between coordinates

```
40.638642, -73.949676
40.626591, -73.935857
```

EDIT: I edited the title and the post, since the comment showed me that the actual problem for me is the term "great circle". So how do I have to understand this puzzle refereing to great circle?

Like this?
[image: c]

And how should I solve the puzzle?
What I am not gettint is what this is aiming at. So the great circle is around the complete earth? Then my scatch is wrong, because I only connected both points? So it is meant that the path is described by those two points and the satelitte itself is cycling around the world, where his path can be described by these two points? Mh, I am baffled....

Answer (score 1):

I believe you [are a bit off course](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/654336/2)…

Your quoted text speaks about a [*great* circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle), which is a geodesic of a sphere. So on the sphere, the shortest connection between two points along the surface is a great circle arc, not a straight line in space. Think about e.g. the equator of the eath. In your map this could well be approximated by a straight line, although if the points were further away, then you might have to take curvature and map projection into account. Drawing a simple planar circle in the map you depicted is certainly not what the term great circle refers to.

In a second step, you'd take offset curves at an offset of 1200m on either side of that path. On the sphere, these would be circles but not great circles. Think about parallels in the geographic term, which are offset curves to the equator. But in your map, if you approximate the great circle path by a straight line, then these would simply be parallel lines.

To explicitely answer your question about the center and radius of the circle: its center would be the center of the earth, and its radius would be the radius of the earth. That's pretty much the definition of a great circle.

Since you now ask about intuition regarding these circles, here is an illustration:

[image: Circles on a sphere]

The blue circle is a great circle. Its center is the center of the sphere, and its radius is the radius of the sphere. The red circles are offset curves. They have the same distance from the blue curve, but are not great circles. Of course, in this case the red curves would be far more than 1200m away from the blue one, at least if the sphere were really the earth.

Comment: Thanks for this important hint! Unfortunately I am not so good at math so I am not used to "great circle". I did not understand how to imagine this setting, could you draw how this great circle lies in this case study so that I can imagine it? Or how do I approach this now?

Comment: See my edit: So you mean the blue line would represent the satelitte path and the black line could be a approx ignoring the curvature?

Comment: The red curves are now offset (in this scatch this should represent the 1200m) but how would the "correct" red lines look? These are now just parallels to the straight black line, but how would the correct solution look like? 

I cannot imagine how to solve this case study in this way with the great circles, could you help me further please?

Comment: @StatTistician: See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Yyj.png) (from [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/328450/35416)) for a great circle on the sphere (red). On the scale of your map, the difference between great circle and straight line would be negligible. So although your edited in picture is correct *in principle*, the difference between black and blue is exaggerated very much. You can use Google Earth to draw great circle paths, and at this scale they'll look like straight lines.

Comment: But how to solve the case study then?

Comment: @StatTistician: Simply use straight lines, it's accurate enough.

Comment: I mean, how to solve the case study and how to draw the red lines with taking the curvature into account? Ths curavture makes the blue line "go into the heaven", so the red lines are still just straight lines shifted 1200 m to left and right?

Comment: I mean, I cannot imagine this correlty taking the curvature into account? I mean still from looking at it above the blue line is still a straight line? So even if I have a long distance from e.g. Berlin to Tokyo, from looking above at it, it is still a straight blue line? So when I then have to think about the distance of 1200m I would still just have to add two straight red lines?

Comment: @StatTistician: Berlin to Tokyo is a completely different matter. In that case, for the “I want to draw this on a map” problem, you'd have to be very precise as to what map, i.e. what projection. For the “I want to locate a person” problem, I'd suggest generating the corresponding area as an KML file and looking at it in Google Earth. Or use some other GIS software if you have some. Details might be best discussed on [the GIS SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).